# Ошибка загрузки ГИТЛАБ на UBUNTU

Tags: nginx, gitlab

Устанавливаю gitlab на ubuntu 16, nginx + php-fpm по официальной документации - https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu

после команды:

```
sudo EXTERNAL_URL="http://gitlab.site.com" apt-get install gitlab-ee
```

выходит ошибка:

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8] (postgresql::enable line 80) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8 ----
STDOUT: The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "gitlab-psql".
This user must also own the server process.
STDERR: initdb: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8 ----
Ran /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8 returned 1

Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 147 resources updated in 36 seconds
dpkg: error processing package gitlab-ee (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab-ee
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locale
```